# Sequelize Eager Loading Error

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm getting an issue where include in my query isn't working, and I can't figure out why. I have two models: Question and Suggestion.

```
Question:
var Question = sequelize.define('Question', {
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function (models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        Question.belongsTo(models.User, {
          as: 'askerId',
          foreignKey: 'askerId'
        })

        Question.belongsTo(models.User, {
          as: 'winnerId',
          foreignKey: 'winnerId'
        })

        Question.hasMany(models.Suggestion)
        Question.hasMany(models.TagQuestion)
      }
    }
  })
```

Suggestion:

```
var Suggestion = sequelize.define('Suggestion', {
    text: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function (models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        Suggestion.belongsTo(models.Question, {
          foreignKey: 'questionId',
          as: 'question'
        })

        Suggestion.belongsTo(models.User)

        Suggestion.hasMany(models.Vote)
      }
    }
  })
```

And my attempted query is here:

```
Question.findAll({
    include: [{
      model: models.Suggestion
    }]
  })
```

But I keep getting the error: `SequelizeEagerLoadingError: Suggestion is not associated to Question!`

Why are they not associated? They are in my database (based on my migration that I wrote). And how should I set up my associations if I am currently doing it incorrectly? I've looked at other people with this issue and not been able to figure out why my associations are wrong.

Comment: What version of sequelize you use? if gt v4 see my answer in topic [How sequelize works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46544418/how-sequelize-works/46545289#46545289) (classMethods and instanceMethods are removed in sequelize v4)

Comment: Yeah, that helped a lot. I'm still having some issues with join table queries (it's linked but it's not finding the objects linked through the join table).

Comment: update your question, add example what actually you do. What type of association? Or you have errors with all types? What error you got?

Comment: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#top-level-where-with-eagerly-loaded-models
From the official doc: If an association is aliased (using the as option), you must specify this alias when including the model.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this error because I had a bad syntax. I was using

```
include: {
  model: db.modelOne,
  model: db.modelTwo
}
```

without the brackets []. Including it solved the error.
Anyway, the [mentioned docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#nested-eager-loading) give this much cleaner option to include all the foreign models recursively:

```
User.findAll({ include: [{ all: true, nested: true }]});
```

Comment: Add description to link

Answer (score 2):

Please check out your `init-models.js`, code like this:

```js
  question.hasMany(suggestion, { as: 'suggestion', foreignKey: 'questionId'});
  suggestion.belongsTo(question, { as: 'question', foreignKey: 'questionId'});
```

is exist ?

from

```
"sequelize": "^6.6.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize no longer supports classMethods. classMethods and instanceMethods are removed.

Previous:

```
const Model = sequelize.define('Model', {
    ...
}, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: function (model) {...}
    },
    instanceMethods: {
        someMethod: function () { ...}
    }
});
```

New:

```
const Model = sequelize.define('Model', {
    ...
});
```

// Class Method

```
Model.associate = function (models) {
    ...associate the models`enter code here`
};
```

Refrence: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html#breaking-changes