# Nodejs sequelize hasMany issue

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I've breaking my head over this sequelize to get the products questions and also to include its answers as well

```
const ProductQuestions = sequelize.define('product_questions', {
  user: {
     type: Sequelize.BIGINT
  },
  product: {
     type: Sequelize.BIGINT
  },
  question: {
     type: Sequelize.TEXT
  }
});

ProductQuestions.associate = function(models) {
   ProductQuestion.hasMany(models.product_answers,{
       foreignKey: 'question',
       as: 'questionId'
    });
}

const ProductAnswer = sequelize.define('product_answers', {
  question: {
     type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
     field: 'questionId'
  },
  answer: {
     type: Sequelize.TEXT
  },
  user: {
     type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
     field: 'userId'
  }
});

ProductQuestiosn.findAll({include: ['product_answers']});
```

for some reason when I that, the columns is wrong when the query runs

```
SELECT 
"product_questions".*, 
"product_answers"."id" AS "product_answers.id", 
"product_answers"."questionId" AS "product_answers.questionId",
"product_answers"."answer" AS "product_answers.answer", 
"product_answers"."userId" AS "product_answers.user", 
"product_answers"."productQuestionId" AS "product_answers.productQuestionId" 
FROM (
SELECT 
"product_questions"."id", 
"product_questions"."productId" AS "product", 
"product_questions"."question", 
"product_questions"."userId" AS "user", 
FROM 
"product_questions" AS "product_questions") 
AS "product_questions" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "product_answers" AS "product_answers" 
ON "product_questions"."id" = "product_answers"."productQuestionId"
```

not sure why is

```
ON "product_questions"."id" = "product_answers"."productQuestionId"
```

when it should be

```
ON "product_questions"."id" = "product_answers"."questionId"
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

so i figured it out!

so it appears that I have to name my columns properly

for the product_answers table in my postgres database, I had the column questionId but it should be named productQuestionId.  I guess it's for naming convention, i can't just name the foreign key the way i want.

Comment: Yes you can. It needs to b two way relation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46544418/how-sequelize-works/46549852#46549852